# Laggy movement/synchronization between clients using JS, socketio, nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I've been trying to make a program using nodejs, socketio, js, where i can move a circle in a Canvas, and all other clients share that circle and it's position.

So moving one in any client, moves the rest, and vice-versa. The server handles the position, and emits it back to all client

each client does it's own rendering.

the problem is, movement becomes laggy everytime i move. It's as if the server got the location from the client, but it's a little bit off, and then emits it, and the cycle repeats.

It's also worth nothing that it's more laggy the more clients are connected. But even with no clients except the one i use, it's still a bit laggy. And it's related to the server real-time updates.

Video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfFeE.gif (this is with 2 total clients, movement is synced but laggy)

video 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnHnd.gif

video 3: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4r1LV.gif

 Server code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const path = require('path');


app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/static'));

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});


let playerLoc = {
    X: 50, 
    Y: 50,
}

function sendNewPos()
{
    io.sockets.emit("newPos", playerLoc); //Send current server location to all clients
}


io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log("User Connected");

    socket.on("clientPos", newPosData => { //get current Pos from all clients to then sync them together
        playerLoc = newPosData;
    })

});


setInterval(() => {
    console.log("here:" +  playerLoc.Y + " and X: " + playerLoc.X);
}, 22 );

setInterval(() => {
    sendNewPos();
}, 100);



http.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Client code:

```js
//socket.on('num', (counter) => {
//$lst.appendChild(newItem(`hello - ${counter}`));

let player = {
    moveW: false,
    moveD: false,
    moveS: false,
    moveA: false,
}


let playerLoc = {};

var socket = io.connect(); 


socket.on("newPos", newLoc =>{ // get pos from client at the start so playerLoc isn't undefined
    playerLoc = newLoc;
});

function render()
{
    let c = document.getElementById("screen");
    let ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, screen.width, screen.height)
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(playerLoc.X, playerLoc.Y, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI); // 100 ix X, 75 is Y (first ix X, second is Y)
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
}


document.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
    if (event.keyCode == 87) // w 
    {
        player.moveW = true;
    }

    if (event.keyCode == 68) // d
    {
        player.moveD = true;
    }

    if (event.keyCode == 83) // s
    {
        player.moveS = true;
    }

    if (event.keyCode == 65) // a
    {
        player.moveA = true; 
    }
})


document.addEventListener("keyup", event => {
    if (event.keyCode == 87) // w 
    {
        player.moveW = false;
    }

    if (event.keyCode == 68) // d
    {
        player.moveD = false;
    }

    if (event.keyCode == 83) // s
    {
        player.moveS = false;
    }

    if (event.keyCode == 65) // a
    {
        player.moveA = false; 
    }
})


function move()
{
    if (player.moveW)
    {
        playerLoc.Y -= 5;
       
    }

    if (player.moveD)
    {
        playerLoc.X += 5;
        
    }

    if (player.moveS)
    {
        playerLoc.Y += 5;
        
    }

    if (player.moveA)
    {
        playerLoc.X -= 5;
        
    }
}



setInterval(() => {
    move();
}, 15);

setInterval(() => {
    render();
}, 15);






socket.on("newPos", newLoc =>{ //get newPos from Server
    playerLoc = newLoc;
    console.log("Y: " + playerLoc.Y + "X: " + playerLoc.X);
    console.log("boom");
});

setInterval(() => { //send current Position to server, which the server then uses to send to all clients so positions update correctly
    socket.emit("clientPos", playerLoc)
}, 50);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues causing what you are seeing:

Firstly, you probably should make your server authoritative. What this means is that only the server is allowed to transmit the exact X,Y coordinates of the player. If there is only one source of truth for the exact position of X,Y it will substantially reduce the 'fighting' over where the circle is.

Instead of sending coordinates, the clients would send updates like 'I want to move up', 'I want to stop moving up' - this will allow the server to remain in control of the exact position, but still give the clients influence over it.

Secondly, because the client is not in complete control of the 'player' object, it is inevitably going to experience jitter to some extent when the server overwrites the client's local copy of the data.

You can somewhat reduce this by using interpolation to smooth transitions to the new location, and to infer from additional data (eg. server sends 'position is X,Y, and the player is moving to the RIGHT at this moment') where it is going to be next frame.

If you send information like this (which way the player object is moving) you don't need to send so much data, which will allow your clients to see less hiccups as these will occur whenever the data received from the server overwrites the local copy with different values.

For example, server can send 'Player is now moving left, from X,Y' the clients can then simulate that movement themselves so the server will not have to send another update until one of the clients presses a button again.

If you want to get more complex still, you can start to measure the latency between each client and the server (how long does it take to send and receive a message) and use that to predict the offset of data.